# What is approximate tax deduction for this scenario?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction

I am working as software Er and my finance status is like this:

```
Basic salary:18750
House rent allowance:7500
Medical allowance : 800
Conveyance Allowance : 1250
Special allowance : 9200
Total earning : 37500

Professional tax : 200
TDS : 2022
Total deduction per month : 2222
```

so how much tax saving could be done here?

I have only house rent proof only for tax saving.

Answer (score 1):

> House rent allowance:7500

House Rent can be tax free to the extent [less of]

- Actual HRA Received
- 40% of Basic for other cities, 50% of Basic for Metro's
- Actual rent paid less of 10% of Basic

> Medical allowance : 800

Can be tax free, if you provide medical bills.

> Conveyance Allowance : 1250

Is tax free.

Apart from this, if you invest in any of the tax saving instruments, i.e. Specified Fixed Deposits, NSC, PPF, EPF, Tution Fees, ELSS, Home Loan Principal etc, you can get upto Rs 150,000 deductions. Additional Rs 50,000 if you invest into NPS.

If you have a home loan, upto Rs 200,000 in interest can be deducted.

So essentially if you invest rightly you need not pay any tax on the current salary, apart from the Rs 200 professional tax deducted.

Comment: thanks for this much details. I dont have other saving instrument apart from rent. no bill for medical too. in that situation what will be the deduction

Comment: It would be whatever rent you pay less of 10% of basic.